# Display some parts of a file written in json

Tags: php, json

Below is my JSON file:

```
{
    "example": "1",
    "example2": 2,
    "text": "3",
    "info": {
        "agent": 4,
        "sum": 5,
        "collection": [{
            "Name": "6",
            "Pic": "7"
        } {
            "Name": "8",
            "Pic": "9"
        }, {
            "Name": "10",
            "Pic": "11"
        }]
    }
}
```

How would I display each 'name' and 'pic' I think I need to use a `foreach` loop but don't know how to.

This is all the code I have:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://linktojson.com'));
echo $data['info']['collection'][0]['Name'];
echo $data['info']['collection'][0]['Pic'];
```

Comment: What programming language are you working with? What are you intending to do exactly?

Comment: @venkatKA i'm using php, but am totally totally new to json. i have my json file above and need to display 'name' and 'pic'

Comment: What have you tried? A simple `var_dump` or php.net should be the first step in understanding what json_decode returns.

Comment: please check my post for what i tried

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://linktojson.com'));

echo "<pre>".print_r($data,1)."</pre>";
foreach($data->info->collection as $key){

    echo $key->Pic;
    echo $key->Name;

  }
```

Valid JSON

```
    {
"example": "1",
"example2": 2,
"text": "3",
"info": {
    "agent": 4,
    "sum": 5,
    "collection": [{
        "Name": "6",
        "Pic": "7"
    }, {
        "Name": "8",
        "Pic": "9"
    }, {
        "Name": "10",
        "Pic": "11"
    }]
     }

      }
```

Comment: it doesn't work :( is there a way to see why it doesnt work

Comment: Your JSON string is missing a comma check with the one I posted

Comment: The solution I posted works for me. json_encode converts the json object to stdclass object

Comment: that's true. Though I prefer to work with stdclass objects.